# what is the planned version of ccid in next ubuntu LTS release 16.04.3

Tags: lts

We are going to use "Giesecke & Devrient GmbH StarSign CUT S" which is supported since ccid 1.4.24. Currently used in LTS 16.04.2 is ccid 1.4.22. I couldn't find any roadmap for the next LTS releases.

Comment: 1 small comment: the LTS is 16.04. The .3 means that the hardware stack(!) is added to 16.04. That does not mean the software gets a newer version (that would defy the "stable" definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See the launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ccid):

- The Artful Aardvark (active development) Ccid trunk series: 1.4.27-1  release (universe)
- The Zesty Zapus (current stable release) Ccid trunk series
  1.4.26-1

So the current normal release (17.04) already uses 1.4.26 and the next normal release (17.10) is going to be using 1.4.27.

Unless there is something unforseen (like the maintainers stopping development) the next LTS (18.04) will be using *at least* 1.4.27.

---

16.04 will stick to 1.4.22 but you could install 1.4.24+ yourself: the dependencies are the same for [16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libacsccid1) and [17.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libacsccid1):

```
libc6 (>= 2.14) [amd64]
libc6 (>= 2.17) [arm64, ppc64el]
libusb-1.0-0 (>= 2:1.0.9~)
```

Version numbers are the same so installing the DEB from 17.04 on 16.04 will not be a problem.